# Pandas find exact words from a list and assign Boolean value if found

Tags: python, regex, pandas, text-mining

So, I have dataframe like this,

```
data = {
  "properties": ["FinancialOffice","Gas Station", "Office", "K-12 School"],
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

This is my list,

```
proplist = ["Office","Other - Mall","Gym"]
```

what I am trying to do is using the list I am trying to find out which words exactly matches with the dataframe column and for each word from the dataframe I need to assign a Boolean true/false value or 0/1. It has to be a exact match.

Output like this,

```
properties         flag
FinancialOffice    FALSE
Gas Station        FALSE
Office             TRUE
K-12 School        FALSE
```

So, It returns TRUE for only "**Office**" because it is the exact match from the list. **FinancialOffice** is not because it is not in the list.

This was my approach, it works fine but I need to assign a new Boolean column to df to find out which ones are exact match.

My approach,

```
import re 
s= ','.join(df["properties"]) # gives comma separated values. 

for words in proplist  :
    if re.search(r'\b' + words + r'\b', s):
        print('{0}'.format(words)) ## print out only Office the matching word.
```

Any help is appreciated. It needs to be regex as str.contains cant find exact match.

Comment: Was the issue fixed? Do you need more help?

Answer (score 2):

Try `Series.isin`:

```py
df["flag"] = df["properties"].isin(proplist)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
        properties   flag
0  FinancialOffice  False
1      Gas Station  False
2           Office   True
3      K-12 School  False
```

Comment: Thanks. That take cares of the exact match problem. What if I have FinancialOffice, Office together in the column? It still has to be TRUE because there is Office. How do I approach it? Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You can use map with lambda:

```
df['flag'] = df['properties'].map(lambda x: x in proplist)
```

or for better performance use set before looking

```
df['flag'] = df['properties'].map(lambda x: x in set(proplist))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try converting `prop_list` into a `set` then using [`pandas.Series.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html#pandas-series-isin):

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd
   ...: 
   ...: d = {"properties": ["FinancialOffice", "Gas Station", "Office", "K-12 School"]}
   ...: df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
   ...: df
Out[1]: 
        properties
0  FinancialOffice
1      Gas Station
2           Office
3      K-12 School
In [2]: prop_list = ["Office", "Other - Mall", "Gym"]
In [3]: df["flag"] = df["properties"].isin(set(prop_list))
   ...: df
Out[3]: 
        properties   flag
0  FinancialOffice  False
1      Gas Station  False
2           Office   True
3      K-12 School  False
```